# Stopping a web application during JBoss startup, when fatal error encountered

Tags: destroy, app-startup, jboss-eap-6

In one of the applications that is in development, we have a home-grown cache manager that is a spring bean. It's init method gets called when this web application starts up in JBoss (EAP 6.0 to be specific).

As the application is still in development, there are cases when a developer starts the application that certain database master data tables that are mentioned to be cached are not available in the developer's db instance by mistake.

Is there a way to stop the web application, when a irrecoverable exception is encountered in such cases, so that the application is not up?